# Saving class instances with different template parameters inside one vector but keep their properties

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like to have a program that parses and manages command-line parameters for me. As you can see in the `main`-function, by using simple commands like `Option<int>("number", { "-n", "--number" })` you can specify the type the option's value should have (like `int` in this case), an unique identifier  for each option (like `"number"`), and multiple strings this option can be introduced with. Also, many options should be wrapped in a class called `OptionSet`, which simplifies access to its options.

But in my actual code, I am having several problems right now:

1. I want to store multiple instances of one class with different template parameters within one `std::vector`. For example, in my code, `Option<int>` should be stored in the same vector like `Option<std::string>` and `Option<double>`.
   Maybe it's even possible to store the template parameters separately in another vector?
2. By using `using`, `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_same` I created a type called `OptionHasValue`. If the template parameter `Invert` is false and `T` is `void`, `OptionHasValue` has an invalid type, otherwise it has the type specified by the template parameter `U`.
   The class `OptionValue` uses `OptionHasValue` and a bit of SFINAE magic to decide if it should have the needed methods for supporting the storage of values or not. That is, the first version of `OptionValue` has `OptionHasValue<T>` as its second template parameter, so it becomes invalid (and removed by the compiler) if `T` is `void`. The other version of `OptionValue` has the opposite behavior, because its second template parameter is `OptionHasValue<T, true>` and the `true` inverts the behavior of `OptionHasValue`.
   The class `Option` itself inherits from `OptionValue`, so if you create an option like `Option<void>`, it does not have support for values (that is, it lacks functions like `setValue`, `setValueFromString` and `getValue` as it should). On the other hand, if you create an option like `Option<int>`, the resulting class instance has all of these features.
   The problem now is, that (for example) `OptionSet::process()` accesses both `Option::hasValue` and `Option::setValueFromString`, but the latter is only declared if `Option::hasValue` is true (and the corresponding template parameter for the option is not `void`). But because `Option::setValueFromString` is not wrapped in some kind of template here, the compiler also complains.
3. In my `main`-function I use the function `optionSet.getOptionValue(std::string)`. This function should return the value of an option (after it has been set after `process()` has been called). The difficult thing now is that the return type depends on the return value of `findOptionByIdentifier`, a function which loops through all available options and returns the option with the wanted identifier.
   For example, if `identifier` would be `"number"` (as in the example for an `Option` at the beginning of this question), the return type of `findOptionByIdentifier` would be `Option<int>`, because the only option having the identifier `"number"` is the one which has `int` as its first template parameter, which would finally result in `getOptionValue` having the return type `int`.
   You can see the expected behavior in comments in some of the last lines of the `main`-function.

So, what do I have to change in the following code to fix all these things (and to make it compile)? I am using g++ 5.2.0 (mingw-w64), so I may use any feature of C++11 and C++14.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>



template<typename T, bool Invert = false, typename U = void>
using OptionHasValue = std::enable_if_t<(!std::is_same<T, void>::value) ^ Invert, U>;       //only make this template substitution successful, if (when 'Invert' is false) T is not if type 'void'

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class OptionValue;

template<typename T>
class OptionValue<T, OptionHasValue<T>>             //using SFINAE ("substitution failure is not an error") here
{
    protected:
        T                               value;

    public:
        void setValue(T newValue)
        {
            value = newValue;
        }

        void setValueFromString(std::string newValueStr)
        {
            setValue(boost::lexical_cast<T>(newValueStr));
        }

        T getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        bool hasValue()
        {
            return true;                            //if this class variant is taken by the compiler, the 'Option' that will inherit from it will have a value
        }
};

template<typename T>
class OptionValue<T, OptionHasValue<T, true>>       //the opposite condition (the 'true' inverts it)
{
    //option value is disabled, but to check if a value is available in the derived class, add a function for that (or should I not?)
    public:
        bool hasValue()
        {
            return false;
        }
};



template<typename T>
class Option : public OptionValue<T>
{
    private:
        std::string                     identifier;
        std::vector<std::string>        variants;

    public:
        Option(std::string newIdentifier, std::vector<std::string> newVariants)
        {
            identifier = newIdentifier;
            variants = newVariants;
        }

        bool hasVariant(std::string v)
        {
            return (std::find(variants.begin(), variants.end(), v) != variants.end());
        }

        std::string getIdentifier()
        {
            return identifier;
        }
};



class OptionSet
{
    private:
        std::vector<boost::any>         options;                                //boost::any can't be the right way to do this, or is it?
        std::vector<std::string>        argvVec;

        template<typename T>
        Option<T>& findOptionByIdentifier(std::string identifier)
        {
            for(auto& o : options)
                if(o.getIdentifier() == identifier)                             //of course this doesn't compile, because 'o' will always be of type 'boost::any', but what should I do instead?
                    return o;
            throw std::runtime_error("error: unable to find option by identifier \"" + identifier + "\"\n");
        }

        template<typename T>
        Option<T>& findOptionByVariant(std::string variant)
        {
            for(auto& o : options)
                if(o.hasVariant(variant))                                       //probably almost the same compile error like in 'findOptionByIdentifier'
                    return o;
            throw std::runtime_error("error: unable to find option by variant \"" + variant + "\"\n");
        }

    public:
        template<typename t>
        void add(Option<T> opt)
        {
            options.push_back(opt);                                             //is this the right way to add instances of classes with different template parameters to a vector?
        }

        void setArgvVec(std::vector<std::string> newArgvVec)
        {
            argvVec = newArgvVec;
        }

        void process()
        {
            for(size_t i=0; i<argvVec.size(); i++)
            {
                Option<T>& opt = findOptionByVariant(argvVec[i]);               //of course this doesn't compile either, but what should I do instead?
                if(opt.hasValue())
                {
                    if(i == argvVec.size()-1)
                        throw std::runtime_error("error: no value given for option \"" + argvVec[i] + "\"\n");
                    opt.setValueFromString(argvVec[i]);                         //boost::bad_lexical_cast should be caught here, but that's not important right now
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        T getOptionValue(std::string identifier)
        {
            Option<T>& opt = findOptionByIdentifier(identifier);                //a bit like the call to 'findOptionByVariant' in 'process()'. also, this variable does not have to be a reference
            if(!opt.hasValue())
                throw std::runtime_error("error: option with identifier \"" + identifier + "\" has no value\n");
            return opt.getValue();
        }
};



int main()
{
    OptionSet optionSet;

    //it's not guaranteed that OptionSet::add will always receive a rvalue, I just do it here for shorter code/simplicity
    optionSet.add(Option<void>("help", { "-?", "--help" }));                    //if it's a void-option, the 'Option' does not have a value, if the template parameter is anything else, it has one (like below)
    optionSet.add(Option<std::string>("message", { "-m", "--message" }));
    optionSet.add(Option<int>("number", { "-n", "--number" }));
    optionSet.add(Option<double>("pi", { "-p", "--pi" }));

    optionSet.setArgvVec({ "--help", "-m", "hello", "--number", "100", "--pi", "3.14" });
    optionSet.process();

    std::string message = optionSet.getOptionValue("message");
    int number = optionSet.getOptionValue("number");
    double pi = optionSet.getOptionValue("pi");

    std::cout << "Message: " << message << "\n";        //should output 'hello'
    std::cout << "Number:  " << number << "\n";         //should output '100'
    std::cout << "Pi:      " << pi << "\n";             //should output something like '3.140000'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from using boost::program_options ?

Comment: "Write my code for me" isn't a valid stack overflow question.  > Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @rwols I do not only want my program to have the ability to process command line parameters, I also want to learn many new things about the fascinating world of C++ templates! ;) But if I would want to be productive, I would probably use boost::program_options, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @sigalor Well, if you look at boost::program_options, you can see that all you really have to do is to lexical_cast your held option string to the desired type. There's no other way to read from the terminal after all; it's all strings in the end.

Comment: @xaxxon What isn't clear about the problems with my code exactly? Also, I have already filled the functions I do not know how to write valid C++ for with some kind of pseudo-code that should model the expected behavior sufficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood the question, but I will try to answer it.

> I want to store multiple instances of one class with different
>   template parameters

There is no such thing. A template with different template paramter is a different class. However, you seem to be solving it successfully through `boost::any`. You could also use another **type-erasure** technique - for example, have a non-template parent to all your options, or switch to non-type-erasure `boost::variant`, as it seems like you only have a limited number of possible option types.

> By using using, std::enable_if_t and std::is_same I created a type
>   called OptionHasValue...

First of all, I would not use SFINAE in this example. Simple partial specialization will suffice. As for `opt.setValueFromString(argvVec[i]);` just create a NOOP function in void option class.

As for the last question, just use a templated function which **receives** a reference to the return type, instead of returning it.